# how to block mac address with portsentry

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mac-address

I use portsentry to block ip address who trying to scanning. Now how do I want to block mac address who trying to scanning. Can I use portsentry, or possibly other tools?

Answer (score 1):

The mac-address changes at every hop, so the only way to block this would be to the do an ARP request. With this you risk that the attacker intentionally starts sending the mac addresses of other, legitimate computers on the network and you risk to DoS yourself.